# JavaScript - 'Normalize' array indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for a method to 'Normalize' array indexes in Javascript.
I have a large array ( `_spm` ) containing values with numeric indexes like ( `_spm[201023]` ).

( For You, to understand: Re-indexing the array starting from zero. )

I would need a method to make all the records have a more human-friendly index ( and may also be sorted ).

I mean:

```
function normalize( arrayWithMessedUpIndexes ){ return reIndexedAndOrderedArray }
```

A possible input is the array `_spm` considering that:

```
 _spm[201023] = "s";
 _spm[376615] = "m";
```

A possible output of the method I am looking for ( using the input array above ):

```
 _spm[0] = "s"
 _spm[1] = "m"
```

Comment: Can't you just loop through and push the entries to a new array? Or is there some mystery to this that you are leaving out?

Comment: Would make sense, but isn't there any faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arr = [];
arr [42] = "foo";
arr [1337] = "bar";

arr.filter (function () {return true}); //["foo", "bar"]
```

Now, how does this work?. Let's take a look at [ES5 §15.4.4.20](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.20), which describes the process.

- ... *some initialization steps*
- *9*.  Repeat, while k < len

  - a. Let `Pk` be `ToString(k)`.
  - b. Let `kPresent` be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of `O` with argument `Pk`.
  - c. If `kPresent` is true, then

    - *do the magic*

Since the first initialized index of our example array is 42,
for every `n < 42`, calling `n in arr` or `arr.hasOwnProperty (n)` evaluates to `false`.

Given that, the condition, described in step **9c**, is not met, hence, the index is skipped.

*Note that `[].filter` is ES5 and may not be compatible with older browsers.*

Comment: As far as I know this will not reindex the array's records, will it?

Comment: @StevenPalinkas Yes, it will, I added a little explanation. Looking for a nice Answer on SO that describes those implicit `undefined`. I'll add it when i found one

Comment: @StevenPalinkas didn't found a good one, added an explanation based on the ES5 specification

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes are always sorted so, all you need to do is remove the undesirable elements

```
_spm = _spm.filter(function(v) { return v != undefined });
```

Comment: What a coincidence ^^. No need for the `undefined` check though, unless you want to filter explicit `undefined`s. As the others are implicit and won't get iterated over

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 True. Never had to rely on that behavior before :)